# Is there a word missing in English, an inanimate counterpart of 'whose'?

Tags: grammar

I was taught that “who” is used when referencing humans, and “which” when referencing other life forms and inanimate objects.

Examples: “The man who fell over” vs “the tree which fell over”.

Extending that to who/whose…it would seem to follow that I’d say: “A man whose hands are large” but that I cannot say: “A clock whose hands are large” (because a clock is an inanimate object).

Thus my question: Is there an English word I should use as a simple replacement for “whose” in the sentence above (“A clock ... hands are large.”)

Or is there no such word and thus, as my teacher said, I must reconstruct my sentence to read: “A clock, the hands of which are large…”

Comment: 'Whose' is pressed into doing duty for inanimate objects also.† 'A clock whose hands are large' is perfectly acceptable. 'It's the house whose door is painted red.' [[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whose)] // † 'Whose' cannot be so used as the wh-question-word. 'Which house's door is painted red?' not 'Whose ...?', which must refer to the owner.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "that".